# Plot depicting for which years I have data available

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have population abundance data for various years (within three different locations):

| Location | X1950 | X1951 | X1952 | X1953 | X1954 | X1955 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wreck Island | NA | 5 | 9 | NA | 6 | 8 |
| Heron Island | 17 | 22 | 29 | 32 | NA | 90 |
| Sunshine Coast | NA | NA | 12 | NA | 60 | 72 |

What I would like to do is create a plot where the X axis is year, and on the Y-axis is Location, and create a dot on the plot for each year that I do have data available for the particular location (So, in this instance, the actual population abundance values are irrelevant).

I am working in the R software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: plot]

Create a `data.frame` with your data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
    Location=c("Wreck Island","Heron Island","Sunshine Coast"),
    X1950=c(NA,17,NA), X1951=c(5,22,NA), X1952=c(9,29,12),
    X1953=c(NA,32,NA), X1954=c(6,NA,60), X1955=c(8,90,72))
```

Create an empty plot with the years (taken from the column labels of your `dataset`, with the leading `X` removed by `substr()`, then coerced by `as.numeric()`) on the horizontal axis and an empty vertical axis:

```
par(mai=c(.5,1.5,.1,.1))
plot(range(as.numeric(substr(names(dataset)[-1],2,99))),c(0.5,nrow(dataset)+0.5),
    type="n",xlab="",ylab="",las=1,yaxt="n")
```

Write the `Location` on the vertical axis. We need to `rev`erse it, otherwise the first location will be written at the bottom.

```
axis(2,1:3,rev(dataset$Location),las=1)
```

Walk through locations, and plot a dot wherever the corresponding entry is not `NA`. Note that the y coordinate of course counts from the bottom, whereas we count table rows from the top, so we need to calculate the y coordinate as `nrow(dataset)+1-loc`, which is precisely the same operation as using `rev()` above.

```
for ( loc in 1:nrow(dataset) ) {
    index <- !is.na(dataset[loc,-1])
    points(as.numeric(substr(names(dataset)[-1][index],2,99)),
        rep(nrow(dataset)+1-loc,sum(index)),
        pch=19)
}
```

Comment: Congrats on reaching 100K rep Stephan!  Well-deserved.

Comment: @Ben: thank you!